# Magento: viewing sample data/sample store on the front

Tags: magento

I've installed the sample data from the magento site. Then also
installed magento with each mysql table configured to be named
with the magento_ prefix so as to tell the magento system tables
apart from the data tables. But I have the following problem (yes,
I installed the data first, and then magento, so that's not the issue):

The main content area when I http to localhost/magento/index.php
is blank. I don't see any data. I was expecting to see the
Magento sample store with sample category pages etc...

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Just did another install of the magento sample data and then magento, but this time leaving as much off all the defaults intact as possible, and here we go, the sample data finally does appear inside magento. Not sure if the fact that the sample data tables did not have a custom prefix as the other tables is what made my previous installation stale or whether something else went wrong.

Comment: This isn't a programming related question. Stack Overflow is about programming questions. Perhaps try posting this on Server Fault?

Comment: Hmmm..., seems like other than stackoverflow there is also a stackexchange and now also a serverfault, all sharing the same general page layout design. Where can I find a complete list of these sites so that I may better choose the place most appropriate appropriate for any given topic in the future? Thanks. John Goche

Comment: Check down at the bottom of this page. Right down the bottom. They're all there. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Been having the same problem, it seems that you cannot use a table prefix in your installation  if you want the sample data to show up.